# ROracle encoding issues

Tags: roracle

I am using the ROracle library to access an Oracle database from RStudio. Please see the code below:

```
drv = dbDriver("Oracle")
connect.string = paste(
  "(DESCRIPTION=",
  "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=", host, ")(PORT=", port, "))",
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=", sid, ")))", sep = "")

con = dbConnect(drv, username = "",
                 password = "",dbname=connect.string, encoding="latin1")

### Pull tables
keyword = dbGetQuery(con, "select COLUMN1,COLUMN2 from TABLE1")
```

In my column i got the words: Lørdag, søndag etc which is returned as: L?rdag, S?ndag.

**R Session Info:**

R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] stringi_1.1.5     doParallel_1.0.11 iterators_1.0.8   ROracle_1.3-1     DBI_0.7           foreach_1.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.2   tools_3.4.2      codetools_0.2-15

Answer (score 2):

Finally works! Apparently i couldnt find any way to force encoding in my code. However, i added the environment variable "NLS_LANG" and the corresponding langauge code to my operating system which fixed the issue