# Setting correct NLS_LANG on Mac for a Oracle database with WE8MSWIN1252

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, roracle

I'm having issues importing norwegian characters like æ, ø, and å from an Oracle database using ROracle. I've previously posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366322/encoding-in-roracle) without finding an answer.

However, I think there might be a solution in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807009/roracle-encoding-issues/52403406#52403406), where he writes:

> However, i added the environment variable "NLS_LANG" and the
>   corresponding langauge code to my operating system which fixed the
>   issue

What would be the correct way of doing this? The Oracle database I´m trying to connect to has `NLS_CHARACTERSET WE8MSWIN1252`, what would the corresponding settings be on a Mac? I've tried setting the locale in terminal with `export LC_ALL=UTF-8` in terminal, but with no luck.

Comment: You must set your `NLS_LANG` variable according to character set of your terminal, i.e. if you set `LC_ALL=UTF-8` then your `NLS_LANG` must be `.AL32UTF8`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783902/odbcconnection-returning-chinese-characters-as/33790600#33790600

Comment: That fixed it, thanks!